# Can't access SDK Tools to install NDK

Tags: android

The link of my problem !
https://s15.postimg.org/x701w317v/New_Bitmap_Image.jpg
I am just beginning to learn Android, thanks to help me !

Comment: So why can't you just download the NDK from [its official website](https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/index.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shoukd avoid spaces in full directory path
eg `c:\Users\thanthung\AppData\Local\Android\SDK` should not contain white spaces as yours do.
You can change the SDK directory to be eg `C:\Android\SDK` and change its path in android studio. Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4938098/ndk-build-error)